# Front tires hitting struts

Tags: tires, mazda, struts

2006 Mazda 5 Sedan front tires are hitting while traveling. There is lots of clearance when not moving. We just put 4 brand new tires on 4200 miles ago. Drivers side rubbed a little on the side but it was the top of the tire hitting the strut bracket that cut it up like a lathe. Causing it to blow. The passenger side is just hitting the top and cutting through bad enough to show the metal cords. The old tires are the same size as the new. So would it be the struts or could it be the tire manufacturer. Or possibly something else.

Comment: Can you clarify - is there clearance when the steering is forward but not when turning? Or is it the shocks compressing that makes the tire hit? Either way it's not the tire manufacturer - as long as you have the right size tire on, the manufacturer is irrelevant. Photos would be a useful help

Answer (score 1):

If you've got plenty of space when stationary, then something is allowing the wheel to move more than it should - most likely a failed bush or joint. Jack the car up and support it on axle stands, then check the suspension for movement. Try to shake the wheel in various directions, and try getting an assistant to turn the steering wheel from one side to the other while you watch the wheel and suspension. This should reveal the culprit...